# Different Titanium HTTPClient behavior from sdk 1.7.5 to 1.8.0.1

Tags: sdk, httpclient, titanium

I found two different behaviors for Titanium HTTPClient in sdk 1.7.5 and 1.8.0.1

Here's my complete code:

```
function Synchronizer () {
//server calls
var callStack = [{
            url: 'http://url1',
            name: 'foo1'
            },
            {
            url: 'http://url2',
            name: 'foo2'
            },
            {
            url: 'http://url3',
            name: 'foo3'
            },
            {
            url: 'http://url4',
            name: 'foo4'
            }
    ];

//processing data
var dataStack = new Array();

//call stack pointer
var stackPointer = 0;

//HTTPClient
var httpClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror:function(e){
            UIManager.SynchronizeUI.onError();
        },
        ondatastream:function(e)    {   
            UIManager.SynchronizeUI.setProgressBarValue(stackPointer);  
        }
    });

//....

//DataConsumer
var DataConsumer = new DataConsumer();

//Method for synchronization
this.synchronizeAll = function (usr, pwd) {

    if(!Ti.Network.online){
      Ti.API.info('Not connected to the internet');
      return;
    }

    Ti.API.info('Avvia syncro');
    stackPointer = 0;

    //Autentication call
    httpClient.open('POST', 'http://url/login');
    httpClient.onload = function() {
        // If authenticated
        if(this.responseText.trim() == ('OK,' + usr)) {
            Ti.API.info('Login successful');
            consumeCallStack();
        }
        //else
        else {
            //...               
        }


    }
    httpClient.send({username: usr, password: pwd, ajaxlogin: 'true'});
    Ti.API.info('Calling login..');
}

/*
 * stack consumer
 */
function consumeCallStack() {

    Ti.API.info('Execute call ' + stackPointer);

    httpClient.open('GET', callStack[stackPointer].url);

    httpClient.onload = function(){
            alert(httpClient.responseText);
            //data
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            Ti.API.info('Retrieved data for ' + callStack[stackPointer].name);
            //..
        }
    httpClient.send(); 
}
```

HTTPClient retrieves the data and the on error function isn't involved.
The problem is that after being authenticated the HTTPClient second call gets the JSON that I want if running with 1.7.5 while gets the same successful login page of the first call with 1.8.0.1. May be a cookie not enabled problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: No error message at all!

Comment: what does `onerror = function(){ }` do for you? Looks good to me

Comment: onerror = function() {} shows me an error message. I'm sure that httpClient retrives the data but I've noted just now that compiling in 1.7.5 the data retrieved is the correct json while when compiling in 1.8.0.1 the data retrieved is the previous login successful page. Any ideas?

Comment: please show the error you get, and the JSON (edit your question)

Comment: Is it possible that is due to the not cookie support in sdk 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

Use the release notes to see which bug fixes relate to your issue:

- [Titanium 1.8.0.1 Release Notes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/release-notes/?version=1.8.0.1)
- [httpclient sync mode](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129766/httpclient-sync-mode)
- [iOS: Http request sent twice on ios 5](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6016)